# Selenium MoveToElement not working if element not found by XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Having issues with the MoveToElement function in Selenium Webdriver for C#. The MoveToElement doesn't seem to do anything.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="rounded-navigation-with-icons">
    <ul>
        <li class="navigation-item">
            <a href="Members" target="_self" class="navigation-item-title"></a>
            <ul>                    
                <li>
                    <a href="MembersTestPage" target="_self"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The inner-most list is hidden initially, until the navigation-item is hovered over by the mouse.

I then have the following code to click the navigation-item-title, which is visible to Selenium, and then click the MembersTestPage link.

```
    public bool SearchForElement(string elementToFind, Page.FindBy by)
    {
        var navigation = Page.FindElement("rounded-navigation-with-icons", Page.FindBy.ID);
        if (navigation != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in navigation.FindElements(By.ClassName("navigation-item")))
            {
                var titleElements = Page.FindElements("navigation-item-title", Page.FindBy.ClassName);
                Actions action = new Actions(Driver.Instance);
                foreach (var moveToItem in titleElements)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Move to the main navigation link container element, but it doesn't work
                        action.MoveToElement(moveToItem);

                        // Move the mouse position manually to the link's location
                        action.MoveByOffset(moveToItem.Location.X, moveToItem.Location.Y);

                        // This does correctly find the element
                        var element = Page.FindElement("a[href='MembersTestPage']", Page.FindBy.CssSelector);
                        action.MoveToElement(element);

                        // Click returns that the element is hidden/invisible and therefore cannot be clicked
                        element.Click();
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

You can see I have used MoveToElement by passing the element, and also by manually passing the X and Y values of the item, but neither are working.

If I find the elements by XPath, this works as expected.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `Actions` in Selenium, then you have to finally call the `Perform()` method, bc otherwise the actions are only collected internally but never executed in the browser.

You can either call

```
action.Perform();
```

or

```
action.Build().Perform();
```

It doesn't matter. If you omit the `Build()`, then `Perform()` implicitly calls it.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Can't believe it was so simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem recently and my solution was to perform everything as one action:

```
action.MoveToElement(moveToItem)
      .MoveByOffset(moveToItem.Location.X, moveToItem.Location.Y)
      .MoveToElement(Page.FindElement("a[href='MembersTestPage']", Page.FindBy.CssSelector))
      .click(Page.FindElement("a[href='MembersTestPage']", Page.FindBy.CssSelector))
      .build()
      .perform();
```